# f:table incompatible with unique constraint?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I'm working on a very basic Grails application in order to dip my toes into web development.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck at trying to display a collection within my MongoDB database using the <f:table>-field tag.... Because the tag somehow seems to be incompatible with the unique constraint of my domain class? Is there anything I can do?

Here's the error message:

**There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/teaser/index.gsp:17] Error executing tag <f:table>: Exception thrown applying constraint [unique] to class [class com.test.site.Teaser] for value [true]: Cannot invoke "grails.gorm.validation.Constraint.isValid()" because "c" is null**

My BootStrap contains two object instances for testing purposes; they seem to be working fine, since they appear in my MongoDB. Just to be safe, here is how I stored them:

```
new Teaser(imageUrl: "", teaserUrl: "", name: "mainTeaser", text: "").save()

new Teaser(imageUrl: "", teaserUrl: "", name: "footerTeaser", text: "").save()
```

Here's my domain class:

```
package com.test.site

class Teaser {

    String imageUrl
    String teaserUrl
    String name
    String text

    static mapWith = "mongo"

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
        name unique: true
    }
```

Here's the current state of my index.gsp (linked to my controller):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <asset:stylesheet href="styles.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Teaser Details</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<header class="header">

</header>
<main class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
                <f:table collection="${teaserList}"/>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, here's my controller:

```
package com.test.site


class TeaserController {

    static scaffold = Teaser

    def index() {
        def teaserList = Teaser.list()
        render view: "index", model: [teaserList : teaserList]
    }
```

I'm grateful for any help :)

Comment: Does changing your constraints block to `name blank: false, unique: true` make any difference?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/